# Jupyter notebook widgets.Button do not show up when putting in try and except block

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on Windows and Jupyter notebook. I was trying to execute a try and except block, in a Jupyter cell, with some `widgets.Button` within but it does not work. 
I have simplified the situation in the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def widget(description):
    button = widgets.Button(description=description,layout={'width': '300px'})
    return button

try:
    print("Before widget_1")
    widget_1 = widget(description='Browser One')
    widget_1
    print("After widget_1")
except:
    pass

widget_2 = widget(description='Browser Two')
widget_2
```

After executing the Jupyter cell it will print `" Before widget_1"` and `"After widget_1"`, and then `widget_2` will show up.

```
Browser Two
```

However, `widget_1` does not show up.

Any idea why it does not work as I expected ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here [jupyter/help](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/435) by [minrk](https://github.com/minrk), `widgets` only show up on the page when they are displayed, to do so use `display(widget)`

`widget_2` is being displayed there because it is the last statement in the cell, which IPython interprets as the 'result' of the cell, so it gets displayed automatically.

If we change the `try/except` block of the above code to the following:

```
try:
    print("Before widget_1")
    widget_1 = widget(description='Browser One')
    display(widget_1)
    print("After widget_1")
except:
    pass
```

The code will work as expected. It means `widget_1` and `widget_2` will show up.